# Fetch records using where clause on joined table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel

I have a model `Voting` that has a `has_many` relation to another model `GroupVoting`. The tables look like this:

```
Voting      GroupVoting
- id        - id 
            - voting_id
            - party_id
            - yes     [int]
            - no      [int]
            - abstain [int]
            - absent  [int]
```

My question is this: **What query should I write to fetch all votings on which a party A has `N` votings "yes" and another party has `M` votes "no", third party... and so on?** (We are given the party ids, the vote type to count and the minimum vote count)

**So far my code looks like this:**

```
gv = GroupVoting.arel_table
Voting.joins(:group_votings)
  .where(
       (gv[:party_id].eq(9).and(gv[:yes].gt(30)))
    .or(gv[:party_id].eq(115).and(gv[:yes].gt(80)))
    .or(gv[:party_id].eq(16).and(gv[:no].gt(60))))
 .group("voting_id").having("count(*)>2").count
```

and the corresponding sql query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, voting_id AS voting_id FROM "votings"
INNER JOIN "group_votings" ON "group_votings"."voting_id" = "votings"."id"
WHERE ((("group_votings"."party_id" = 9 AND "group_votings"."yes" > 25 OR "group_votings"."party_id" = 115 AND "group_votings"."yes" > 60) OR "group_votings"."party_id" = 16 AND "group_votings"."no" > 30))
GROUP BY voting_id HAVING count(*)>2
```

This code seems to work but the result is in the form of:

```
{11666=>3, 11667=>3, 1835=>3}
```

And I want it in the form of:

```
ActiveRecord[Voting..., Voting..., ...]
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Does either table votings or group_votings relate voting_Id to the text "Voting"?  if not then you'll need a case statement on voting_ID and manually assign the text...

Comment: Hi xQbert. I am not sure I understand your question. GroupVoting has voting_id that references the voting model. One voting has many group_votings.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how the 3 gets translated to "Voting"  3 I assume is the voting_Id, but I don't know how the database is to know that 3 means Voting and 4 means something else... etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `count` at the end of your clause which won't return the objects but a `count` for each `id`.  Remove that and you should get the objects back.

Comment: Hi CWitty. If I remove the `count` I get the following error: `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "votings.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. I guess it is because of the inner workings of rails.

Comment: I think you can drop the group and having unless Im not understanding the full need.

Comment: You can also try changing `group_by(:voting_id)` to `group_by(:id)`